# Unicode UTF Converter

Tags: code-golf, unicode

The goal is to create a fully compliant converter between the official Unicode encodings as given in the [UTF FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html). Given that this is centred on Unicode, I will accept the answer with the lowest byte count using the best possible of the involved encodings (which will probably be UTF-8, unless maybe you program it in APL).  I apologize for the long post, but a lot of it is explaining the encodings which can also be accessed in the [official specification (pdf, section 3.9 D90 - D92)](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch03.pdf#G7404), or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Transformation_Format#Unicode_Transformation_Format_and_Universal_Character_Set).

## Specifications

*If at any time your language of choice cannot exactly meet a requirement, substitute it with something that sticks the spirit of the rules given. Eg. not every language has built-in arrays, functions etc.*

- No using string libraries/functions, or encoding libraries/functions. The point of this code golf is to implement the converter using bit/byte manipulation. Using strings themselves in their capacity as a character or byte array is allowed though. Oh, and no OS calls which perform the conversion either.
- The converter is a function which will take three parameters: a byte array representing the encoded input string, and the "input" and "output" encodings represented as numbers. Arbitrarily we will assign `UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32, UTF-32BE, and UTF32LE` numbers from 0 to 6 in that order. There is no need to check if the number is `< 0` or `> 6`, we will assume these parameters are correct. The converter will return a valid byte array in the desired output encoding.
- We will use the null character (`U+0000`) as a string terminator. Anything after this doesn't matter. We will assume that the input array has the null character somewhere so you do not need to do a bounds check.
- As per the [FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html), if the input byte array is invalid for its declared encoding, we must signal an error. We will do this in one of the following ways: crash the program, throw an exception, return null or return an array whose first four bytes are all 0 (so that it can be recognized as `U+0000` in every encoding).

## The Encodings

The official specifications must be followed, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Transformation_Format#Unicode_Transformation_Format_and_Universal_Character_Set) provides a good (and as far as I believe correct) explanation of the encodings, and I will summarize them here for completeness. Note that UTF-16 and UTF-32 have variants for [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

### UTF-32, UTF-32LE, UTF-32BE

The simplest encoding, each code point is simply encoded in 4 bytes equal to its numeric value. LE/BE represents endianness (little endian/big endian).

### UTF-16, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE

Code points from `U+0000 - U+FFFF` are encoded in 2 bytes equal to its numeric value. Larger values are encoded using a pair of *surrogates* which are reserved values from `U+D800 - U+DFFF`. So to encode points greater than `U+FFFF`, the following algorithm can be used (shamelessly copied from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF)):

> - 0x010000 is subtracted from the code point, leaving a 20 bit number in the range 0..0x0FFFFF.
> - The top ten bits (a number in the range 0..0x03FF) are added to 0xD800 to give the first code unit or lead surrogate, which will be in the range 0xD800..0xDBFF [...].
> - The low ten bits (also in the range 0..0x03FF) are added to 0xDC00 to give the second code unit or trail surrogate, which will be in the range 0xDC00..0xDFFF [...].

### UTF-8

Code points from `U+0000 - U+007F` are encoded as 1 byte equal to its numeric value. From `U+0080 - U+07FF` they are encoded as `110xxxxx 10xxxxxx`, `U+0800 - U+FFFF` is `1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx`, higher values are `11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx`. The `x`'s are the bits from the numeric value of the code point.

### BOM

The byte-order mark (BOM, `U+FEFF`) is used as the first code point to indicate endianness. Following the [FAQ guidelines on BOMs](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom10), the BOM will be used as follows: For `UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32` it is optional. If the BOM is absent in `UTF-16` or `UTF-32`, it is assumed to be big endian. The BOM **must not** appear in `UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE and UTF-32BE`.

## Common Pitfalls Causing Invalid UTF

Various things may cause a byte sequence to be invalid UTF.

- **UTF-8 and UTF-32:** Directly encoding surrogate code points ( `U+D800 - U+DFFF` ), or code points greater than `U+10FFFF`.
- **UTF-8:** Many invalid byte sequences.
- **UTF-16:** Unpaired, or improperly paired surrogates.
- **BOM:** Must be used as specified in the encoding section. Note that when outputting `UTF-16` or `UTF-32` (no inherent endianness specified) you can pick, but with little endian, you **must** include the BOM.

Note that non-characters and unassigned code points (both distinct from surrogates) are to be treated like regular characters.

Comment: "No using string libraries/functions, or encoding libraries/functions." What about real built-ins. In APL, [`''⎕R''⍠'InEnc' 'UTF16BE' 'OutEnc' 'UTF8-BOM'`](http://help.dyalog.com/14.0/Content/Language/System%20Functions/r.htm).

Comment: @NBZ Those would not be allowed since the point of this challenge is to implement the behaviour that those provide.

Comment: Note to answerers: I had more or less abandoned this question, but given recent renewed interest, in the coming days, I will take some time to go through the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## C++, (UTF-8) 971 bytes

```c++
#include<cstdint>
using u=uint8_t;using U=uint32_t;U i,o,x,b,m;U R(u*&p){x=*p++;if(!i){m=0;while(128>>m&x)++m;if(m>1)for(x&=127>>m;--m;)x=x<<6|((*p&192)-128?~0:*p++&63);return m?x=~0:x;}else if(i<3){x<<=8;x+=*p++;}else if(i<4){x+=*p++<<8;}else if(i<6){x<<=24;x+=*p++<<16;x+=*p++<<8;x+=*p++;}else{x+=*p++<<8;x+=*p++<<16;x+=*p++<<24;}return x;}U r(u*&p){U x0=R(p);if(i&&i<4&&x>>10==54)x=R(p)>>10==55?(x0<<10)+x-56613888:~0;if(!b++){if(x==65279)if(!i||i%3==1)r(p);else x=~0;else if(x==65534&&i==1)i=3,r(p);else if(x==4294836224&&i==4)i=6,r(p);}return x>1114111||x>>11==27?x=~0:x;}void w(U x,u*&p){if(!o){if(x<128)*p++=x;else{for(m=0;~63<<m&x;m+=6);for(*p++=~127>>m/6|x>>m;m;)*p++=128|x>>(m-=6)&63;}}else if(o<4&&x>65535)x-=65536,w(55296|x>>10,p),w(56320|x&1023,p);else if(o<3)*p++=x>>8,*p++=x;else if(o<4)*p++=x,*p++=x>>8;else if(o<6)*p++=x>>24,*p++=x>>16,*p++=x>>8,*p++=x;else*p++=x,*p++=x>>8,*p++=x>>16,*p++=x>>24;}int t(u*&p,u*&q){for(b=0,x=1;U(x+x);)w(r(p),q);return x;}
```

The readable program below can be condensed to the above form by filtering it through the following Perl command:

```sh
perl -p0 -e 's!//.*!!g;s/\s+/ /g;s/ \B|\B //g;s/0x[\da-f]+/hex($&)/ige;s/#include<[^<>]+>/\n$&\n/g;s/^\n+//mg'
```

The above command

- removes comments
- removes unnecessary whitespace
- converts hexadecimal literals to decimal
- reinstates newlines around `#include` lines

#### Readable code

```c++
#include <cstdint>
using u = uint8_t;
using U = uint32_t;

U   i,                          // input encoding
    o,                          // output encoding
    x,                          // last read value
    b,                          // char count(BOM only valid when b==0)
    m;                          // temporary variable for measuring UTF-8

//   Encodings:
// 0 UTF-8
// 1 UTF-16
// 2 UTF-16BE
// 3 UTF-16LE
// 4 UTF-32
// 5 UTF-32BE
// 6 UTF-32LE

// Read a character or UTF-16 surrogate
U R(u*& p) {
    x = *p++;
    if (!i) { // UTF-8
        m=0; while (128>>m&x) ++m; // how many bytes?
        if (m>1) for (x&=127>>m; --m; ) x = x<<6 | ((*p&192)-128?~0:*p++&63);
        return m ? x=~0 : x;
    } else if (i<3) { // UTF-16, UTF-16BE
        x<<=8; x+=*p++;
    } else if (i<4) { // UTF-16LE
        x+=*p++<<8;
    } else if (i<6) { // UTF-32, UTF-32BE
        x<<=24; x+=*p++<<16; x+=*p++<<8; x+=*p++;
    } else { // UTF-32LE
        x+=*p++<<8; x+=*p++<<16; x+=*p++<<24;
    }
    return x;
}

// Read a character, combining surrogates, processing BOM, and checking range
U r(u*& p) {
    U x0 = R(p);
    if (i && i<4 && x>>10==54)
        x = R(p)>>10==55 ? (x0<<10)+x-56613888: ~0; // 56613888 == 0xd800<<10 + 0xdc00 - 0x10000
    if (!b++) {                 // first char - is it BOM?
        if (x==0xFEFF)
            if (!i || i%3==1)
                r(p); // BOM in UTF-8 or UTF-16 or UTF-32 - ignore, and read next char
            else
                x = ~0; // not allowed in these modes
        else if (x==0xFFFE && i==1)
            i=3,r(p); // reversed BOM in UTF-16 - change to little-endian, and read next char
        else if (x==0xFFFE0000 && i==4)
            i=6,r(p); // reversed BOM in UTF-32 - change to little-endian, and read next char
    }
    return x>0x10ffff || x>>11==27 ? x=~0 : x;
}


// Write character(assumed in-range)
void w(U x, u*& p) {
    if (!o) { // UTF-8
        if (x<128) *p++=x;        // ASCII
        else {
            for (m=0; ~63<<m&x; m+=6); // how many bits?
            for (*p++=~127>>m/6|x>>m; m; ) *p++ = 128|x>>(m-=6)&63;
        }
    } else if (o<4 && x>65535)  // UTF-16 surrogate
        x-=65536, w(0xD800|x>>10,p), w(0xDC00|x&0x3FF,p);
    else if (o<3)  // UTF-16, UTF-16BE
        *p++=x>>8, *p++=x;
    else if (o<4)  // UTF-16LE
        *p++=x, *p++=x>>8;
    else if (o<6)  // UTF-32, UTF-32BE
        *p++=x>>24, *p++=x>>16, *p++=x>>8, *p++=x;
    else  // UTF-32LE
        *p++=x, *p++=x>>8, *p++=x>>16, *p++=x>>24;
}

// Transcode
int t(u*& p, u*& q)                  // input, output
{
    for (b=0,x=1;U(x+x);)    // exit condition is true only for x==-x, i.e. 0 and ~0
        w(r(p),q);
    return x;
}
```

The function to be called is `t()`, with input and output encodings passed in the global variables `i` and `o` respectively, and `p` pointing at the bytes of input, which **must** be null-terminated.  `q` points to the output buffer, which will be overwritten, and **must** be big enough for the result - there is no attempt to avoid buffer overrun.

I hope the code comments are sufficiently explanatory - ask below if one of them is too cryptic (but do make an effort first!).

I compiled a substantial test suite whilst developing this answer; I include it below for the benefit of other entrants, and to document my interpretation of requirements:

#### Test functions

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<u>& v)
{
    out << "{ ";
    for (int i: v) out << i << " ";
    out << "}";
    return out;
}

int test_read(int encoding, std::vector<u> input, U expected)
{
    b = 0;
    i = encoding;
    auto d = input.data();
    U actual = r(d);
    if (actual == expected) return 0;
    std::cerr << std::hex << "Decoding " << encoding << "; " << input << " gave " << actual
              << " instead of " << expected << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

int test_write(int encoding, U input, std::vector<u> expected)
{
    o = encoding;
    u buf[20], *p = buf;
    w(input, p);
    std::vector<u> actual(buf,p);
    if (expected == actual) return 0;
    std::cerr << std::hex << "Encoding " << encoding << "; " << input << " gave " << actual
              << " instead of " << expected << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

int test_transcode(int ienc, std::vector<u> input, int oenc, std::vector<u> expected)
{
    b = 0;
    i = ienc; o = oenc;
    u buf[200], *p = buf, *d = input.data();
    int result = t(d, p);
    std::vector<u> actual(buf,p);
    if (result ? expected.empty() : expected == actual) return 0;
    std::cerr << std::hex << "Encoding " << ienc << " to " << oenc << "; " << input << " gave " << actual
              << " instead of " << expected << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

#### Test suite

```c++
static const U FAIL = ~0;
int main() {
    int e = 0;                        // error count
    // UTF-8
    e += test_read(0, { 128 }, FAIL); // unexpected continuation
    e += test_read(0, { 128, 1 }, FAIL);
    e += test_read(0, { 128, 128 }, FAIL);
    e += test_read(0, { 192, 192 }, FAIL); // start without continuation
    e += test_read(0, { 192, 0 }, FAIL);
    e += test_read(0, { 224, 0 }, FAIL);
    e += test_read(0, { 224, 192 }, FAIL);
    e += test_read(0, { 0xf4, 0x90, 128, 128 }, FAIL); // Unicode maximum+1

    e += test_read(0, { 127 }, 127);
    e += test_read(0, { 192, 129 }, 1); // We accept overlong UTF-8
    e += test_read(0, { 0xc2, 128 }, 128);
    e += test_read(0, { 224, 128, 129 }, 1);
    e += test_read(0, { 0xef, 128, 128 }, 0xF000);
    e += test_read(0, { 0xef, 191, 191 }, 0xFFFF);
    e += test_read(0, { 0xf4, 128, 128, 128 }, 0x100000);
    e += test_read(0, { 0xf4, 0x8f, 191, 191 }, 0x10FFFF); // Unicode maximum

    e += test_read(0, { 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF, 127 }, 127); // byte-order mark

    e += test_write(0, 0, { 0 });
    e += test_write(0, 127, { 127 });
    e += test_write(0, 128, { 0xc2, 128 });
    e += test_write(0, 255, { 0xc3, 191 });
    e += test_write(0, 0xFFFF, { 0xef, 191, 191 });
    e += test_write(0, 0x10FFFF, { 0xf4, 0x8f, 191, 191 });

    // UTF-16
    e += test_read(1, { 0, 1 }, 1);
    e += test_read(1, { 0xd8, 0, 0xdc, 1 }, 0x10001);
    e += test_read(1, { 0xdb, 0xff, 0xdf, 0xff }, 0x10ffff);

    e += test_read(1, { 0xd8, 0, 0xd8, 1 }, FAIL); // mismatched surrogate
    e += test_read(1, { 0xd8, 0, 0, 1 }, FAIL); // mismatched surrogate
    e += test_read(1, { 0xdc, 0 }, FAIL);

    e += test_write(1, 1, { 0, 1 });
    e += test_write(1, 256, { 1, 0 });
    e += test_write(1, 0xffff, { 255, 255 });
    e += test_write(1, 0x10001, { 0xd8, 0, 0xdc, 1 });
    e += test_write(1, 0x10ffff, { 0xdb, 0xff, 0xdf, 0xff });

    // UTF-16LE
    e += test_write(3, 1, { 1, 0 });
    e += test_write(3, 256, { 0, 1 });
    e += test_write(3, 0x10001, { 0, 0xd8, 1, 0xdc });
    e += test_write(3, 0x10fffe, { 0xff, 0xdb, 0xfe, 0xdf });

    // UTF-16 byte-order mark
    e += test_read(1, { 0xFE, 0xFF, 0x0, 1 }, 1); // byte-order mark
    e += test_read(1, { 0xFF, 0xFE, 1, 0x0 }, 1); // reversed byte-order mark
    // disallowed byte-order marks
    e += test_read(2, { 0xFE, 0xFF }, FAIL);
    e += test_read(3, { 0xFF, 0xFE }, FAIL);
    // reversed byte-order mark is an unassigned character - to be treated like regular character, according to question
    e += test_read(2, { 0xFF, 0xFE }, 0xfffe);
    e += test_read(3, { 0xFE, 0xFF }, 0xfffe);

    // UTF-32
    e += test_read(4, { 0, 0, 0, 1 }, 1);
    e += test_read(4, { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, FAIL);
    e += test_write(4, 1, { 0, 0, 0, 1 });
    e += test_write(4, 0x10203, { 0, 1, 2, 3 });

    // UTF-32LE
    e += test_read(6, { 0, 0, 0, 1 }, FAIL);
    e += test_read(6, { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, 1);

    // UTF-32 byte-order mark
    e += test_read(4, { 0, 0, 0xFE, 0xFF,  0, 0, 0, 1 }, 1); // byte-order mark
    e += test_read(4, { 0xFF, 0xFE, 0, 0,  1, 0, 0, 0 }, 1); // reversed byte-order mark
    // disallowed byte-order marks
    e += test_read(5, { 0, 0, 0xFE, 0xFF }, FAIL);
    e += test_read(5, { 0xFF, 0xFE, 0, 0 }, FAIL);
    e += test_read(6, { 0, 0, 0xFE, 0xFF }, FAIL);
    e += test_read(6, { 0xFF, 0xFE, 0, 0 }, FAIL);

    e += test_transcode(1, { 1, 2, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0, 0 }, // That's not a BOM; it's a zwnj when not the first char
                        1, { 1, 2, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0, 0 });
    e += test_transcode(1, { 0xFF, 0xFE, 1, 2, 0, 0 }, // reversed byte-order mark implies little-endian
                        1, { 2, 1, 0, 0 });
    e += test_transcode(4, { 0xFF, 0xFE, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, // reversed BOM means little-endian
                        4, { 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
    e += test_transcode(1, { 0xdb, 0xff, 0xdf, 0xff, 0, 0 }, // U+10ffff UTF-16 to UTF-8
                        0, { 0xf4, 0x8f, 191, 191, 0 });

    return e;
}
```

Comment: Dang.. C++ beat Python.

Comment: @TickTock : while it's technically not "transcoding" per se, my `awk` entry below  does fully encode `UTF-8` and `UTF-32 BE+LE`, all without needing anything fancy like lambda functions…. on top of not having a single hard-coded number

Answer (score 5):

## Python - 1367 UTF-8 chars

Alright! This was an extremely difficult question because of the sheer amount of work it took to understand and implement all the specifications, but I think that I have a correct implementation.

```py
O,P,Q,R=65536,128,b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00',63
def A(x,y):assert x;return y
def B(x):
    o,c=[],0
    for b in x:
        if c:c,v=c-1,A(127<b<192,v<<6)|(b-P)
        else:
            c,v=(b>127)+(b>223)+(b>239),b
            if b>127:v=A(191<b<248,b&(R>>c))
        o+=[v][c:]
    return o[o[0]in(65279,O-2):]
def C(k):
    def o(x,s=None):
        for a,b in zip(x[k::2],x[1-k::2]):
            d=a|(b<<8)
            if s!=None:yield(A(56319<d<57344,d-56320)|(s<<10))+O;s=None
            elif 55295<d<57344:s=A(s<1024,d-55296)
            else:yield d
    return o
def D(x):n=(2,3,1)[[Q[:2],Q[1::-1],x[:2]].index(x[:2])];return C(n&1)(x[n&2:])
E=lambda a,b,c,d:lambda x:[L|(l<<8)|(m<<16) for L,l,m in zip(x[a::4],x[b::4],x[c::4])]
def F(x):n,m=((1,4),(-1,4),(-1,0))[[Q,Q[::-1],x[:4]].index(x[:4])];return E(*range(4)[::n])(x[m:])
S=lambda x,s=0,a=255:(x>>s)&a
G=lambda e:(e,)if e<P else(192|S(e,6),P|(e&R))if e<2048 else(224|S(e,12),P|S(e,6,R),P|(e&R))if e<O else(240|S(e,18),P|S(e,12,R),P|S(e,6,R),P|(e&R))
H=lambda e:(S(e,8),S(e))if e<O else(216|S(e-O,18),S(e-O,10),220+S((e-O)&1023,8),S(e-O))
I=lambda e:(S(e),S(e,8))if e<O else(S(e-O,10),216|S(e-O,18),S(e-O),220+S((e-O)&1023,8))
J=lambda e:(S(e,24),S(e,16),S(e,8),S(e))
K=lambda e:(S(e),S(e,8),S(e,16),S(e,24))
convert=lambda d,i,o:bytes(sum(map(L[o],N(list(M[i](d)))),()))if d else d
L,M=[G,H,H,I,J,J,K],[B,D,C(1),C(0),F,E(3,2,1,0),E(0,1,2,3)]
N=lambda d:[A(-1<x<1114112 and x&~2047!=55296,x)for x in d]
```

`convert` is the function that takes the data 'bytes' object, the input ID, and the output ID. It seems to work - although python seems to have a slightly broken usage of BOMs when unspecified in the encoding, so using python's builtin encoding to test modes 1 and 4 won't work.

Fun fact: The size is also 555<sub>16</sub> or 10101010101<sub>2</sub>.

773 chars for decoding, 452 for encoding, 59 for verification and 83 for miscellaneous parts.

Comment: @TrangOul: Generally, trivial edits (like language tagging) are frowned upon.

Comment: @ZachGates [someone has to make them whether it be <1000 rep users or >1000 rep users, and that someone is the community](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7054/46231)

Comment: That question/answer doesn't show a community consensus. Across the network, trivial edits like these are frowned upon. Neither <1000 nor >1000 rep users should make these edits unless they clearly improve the content or format. It's best to hold off on editing things like language tags, single word corrections/changes, etc. @cat

Comment: I think the size is no longer 0x555 :-(.  But you might get closer using the standard Python-golf tip of using one space for indents.

Comment: @TobySpeight it's 0x557 right now, you're right. And actually, I used tabs, which had to be converted to spaces for posting, but still count as one character. I'll go see if I can shave a couple of characters some other way when I get a chance.

Comment: In any case, I'm still winning since it's the only response to this question!

Comment: *"I'm still winning since it's the only response"* - [no longer](/a/69423/39490)!  I'd actually started work on it before you read my comment...

Comment: @TobySpeight nice! I suppose I'll have to come back to this at some point soon so that I can get back into first place.

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3, 1138 bytes (UTF-8)

So it turns out that 14 hours of international travel is a *fantastic* opportunity to finish off a golfing challenge...

The conversion function is `C()`. This calls `u()`, `v()`, and `w()` to decode, and `U()`, `V()`, and `W()` to encode, UTF-8, -16 and -32, respectively. None of the encoders will output a BOM, but all of the decoders will correctly handle one. Error conditions result in an exception (usually a `ZeroDivisionError`, courtesy of the "die-suddenly" function `E()`).

```py
from struct import*
l=len
j=''.join
b=lambda c:[*bin(c)[2:]]
P,Q,i,o,z,Z='HI10><'
B=65279
O,F,H,L,X=1024,65536,55296,56320,57344
E=lambda:1/0
R=lambda y,e,c,n:unpack(([[z,Z][y[:n]==pack(Z+c,B)],e][l(e)])+c*(l(y)//n),y)
S=lambda d,e:B!=d[0]and d or e and E()or d[1:]
def u(y,d=(),p=0):
 while p<l(y):
  q=b(y[p])
  if l(q)>7:
   x=q.index(o);C=1<x<5and q[x+1:]or E();X=x+p;X>l(y)>E();p+=1
   while p<X:q=b(y[p]);C=l(q)>7and(i,o==q[:2])and(*C,*q[2:])or E();p+=1
   d=*d,int(j(C),2)
  else:d=*d,y[p];p+=1
 return S(d,0)
def T(p):
 q=b(p);C=()
 while l(q)not in(7,11,16,21):q=o,*q
 while l(q)>6:C=int(i+o+j(q[-6:]),2),*C;q=q[:-6]
 return bytes(p<128and[p]or[int(i*(7-l(q))+o+j(q),2),*C])
U=lambda c:b''.join(map(T,c))
def v(y,e=''):
 c=R(y,e,P,2);d=[];n=0
 while n<l(c)-1:h,a=c[n:n+2];D=[(h,a),(F+(h-H)*O+a-L,)][H<=h<L<=a<X];M=3-l(D);n+=M;d+=D[:M]
 if n<l(c):d=*d,c[n]
 return S(d,e)
V=lambda c,e=z:W(sum(map(lambda p:([H+(p-F)//O,L+(p-F)%O],[p])[p<F],c),[]),e,P)
w=lambda y,e='':S(R(y,e,Q,4),e)
W=lambda c,e=z,C=Q:pack(e+C*l(c),*c)
K=(u,U),(v,V),(v,V,z),(v,V,Z),(w,W),(w,W,z),(w,W,Z)
def C(y,f,t):f,_,*a=K[f];_,t,*b=K[t];return t(f(y,*a),*b)
```

Answer (score 2):

This ***ENTIRELY*** self-contained and `POSIX-compliant` `awk` function of my own making, that is

- fully-encapsulated with zero external dependencies
- can now encode any single Unicode code-point, in both `UTF-8` and
  `UTF-32 (BE+LE)`, plus any arbitrary byte, regardless of locale-setting (as long as it's not something like `EBCDIC`). The only part missing is
  `UTF-16`.
- is proven working on `mawk-1/2`, `gawk (in any mode other than -t)`, even `nawk (sans "\0" NUL byte)`, and
- doesn't need loops, recursion, pre-made lookups in any shape or form, or caching/memoization

***Every single*** threshold, range cutoff, scaling factor, and necessary offset (like `xC0 xE0 xF0` etc), both for the auto-detection part and the encoding part, are being dynamically generated on the fly, while requiring only 1 additional temp variable on top of the 2 needed for user inputs anyway.

My own benchmarking of `mawk-2` running it puts it within just 1.7x speed ratio against the built-in encoder in `gawk ( 1.0x )`, which is a decent showing for a user-level function benchmarked against compiled C-code binaries.

- `__` is code-point integer input, with auto-detection for out-of-range values such as `x < 0`, `1114111 < x`, plus the `UTF-16 surrogate ranges`, which would simply print out 1 single arbitrary byte that is its modulo-equivalent.
- `_` is optional - enter `-32` for `UTF32-LE` or `32` for `UTF32-BE`;

  any other non-empty input, e.g. `"1"` or `"/"` or `"\t"` etc, forces it to use the `awk`-built-in `sprintf("%c", x)` single-character encoder, taking the input **as-is**, and printing out 1 character that will be locale-setting specific

  (this feature is most useful when validating against `gawk` in unicode mode)

.

```
jot 1114112 0 | mawk 'BEGIN {  }

function chrUC8(__,_,___) {
    return \
    ((___=_)*_)>=(_+=_+=_^=_<_)^_ \
    ? ( (+___<-___)==(___=(--_+_)^_*(_^=++_))^!_ \
        ? sprintf("%c%c%c%c", (__=int(__) % (_*_*_*_))%_+___,
            int(__/_)%_+___, (__=int(__/_/_))%_+___, int(__/_)+___)\
        : sprintf("%c%c%c%c",  int((__%=_*_*_*_)/_/_/_)+___,
            int(__/_/_)%_+___, int(__/_)%_+___,__%_+___)\
                                 ) \
                                 :  +___  ||
          (((__=+__)+__)<_^_ && -__<=+__) ||
      ((___=(--_+_)^_*++_^_)<=__ && __<(_^_*(_+_)+___)) ||
                                  +__<-__ ||
                              ((_+_)^_*(_*_+_^_))<=__\
        ? sprintf("%c",+___<_?__: (__%(_^=_)+_)%_+___)\
    : (__+__)<(_+_)^_                                  \
        ? sprintf("%c%c", (___+=(_*=_*_)+_) +_+ int(__/_), __%_+___) \
    : __<_^(_+_)                                                    \
        ? sprintf("%c%c%c", _*(_+_) + (___+=(_*=_*_)+_) +_+ int(__/_/_),
                                     int(__/_)%_ + ___, __%_ + ___) \
        : sprintf("%c%c%c%c", _*-_+ (___+=(_*=_*_)+_) +_+_+ int(__/_/_/_),
                int(__/_/_)%_ +___, int(__/_)%_ + ___,__%_+___)  
}'
```

The squeezed form is roughly **789 bytes**, give or take.

How can this form save space at all ?

> e.g. one can write 6 `ASCII`-bytes of `262144` or `2^18` or even `64^3` to scale 3 continuation bytes in the supplementary planes…

> …… or save space via `8^6` or `4^9`.

because truth be told, the number ***4***, and combinations of it, is all you need to encode everything about Unicode :

```
4
16
256
 #
128
 2048
   65536
      1114112
           ##
           64
           4096
             262144
                 ###
                  128
                   192
                    224
                     240
                      #####
                         1048576
                              2048
                                55296
                                   1024
                                     56320
                                        57344
      # gawk profile,
     created Thu Nov 10 14:26:19 2022

     gawk 'BEGIN {
     1     OFS="\f\b\b"
     1     print "",
     _=4,
     _*_,
     _^_,
     "#",
     _*(_+_)*_,
     _^_*(_+_),
     _^(_+_),
     (_+_)^_*(_^_+_*_),
     "##",
     _*_*_,
     (_+_)^_,
     _^(_+_)*_,
     "###",
     _*(_+_)*_,
     _^_-_*_*_,
     _^_-(_+_)*_,
     _^_-_*_,
     "#####",
     _*_^(_+_)*_,
     _^_*(_+_),
     _^_*(_^_-_-(_+_)*_-_),
     _^_*_,
     _^_*(_^_-(_+_)*_-_),
     (_^_-_*_-_*_)*_^_
}'
```